# Samba execute permission is always set

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, samba

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 server that exposes a samba share to Windows machine.
When I connect to the share and create files with notepad, permissions are respected and files don't become executable. However when I use Visual Studio to edit the files, every time I save them, executable bit is flipped on. Some googling uncovered a thread that links wb file open mode with archive attribute on windows and therefore execute bit on Linux.

However given my config, this should not be the case.

```
    read only = no
    acl allow execute always = no
    acl map full contorl = False
    map archive = no
    map system = no
    map hidden = no
    create mask = 0664
    force create mode = 0664
    directory mask = 02775
    force directory mask = 02775
    inherit permissions = False
```

If at all possible I would like to configure samba so that it would just leave the execute permission alone - period.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Don't have a solution, but just in case: you have a typo in your `acl map full contorl` setting.

Comment: Try deleting `acl allow execute always = no`

Answer (score 0):

I added this line to smb.conf:

```
    store dos attributes = no
```

I don't know what this option does, but it helped me.

`map archive = no` is probably required too.